# can't access inner class's public variable... which is inherited from parent

Tags: java, scope

Java Q: I can't access a public variable in my parent's class' inner class called foo. Why? setup is next(pseudo coded for brevity):

```
public class PageObject  
{  
    public class Button  
    {  
        public String foo ="I want this string."  //can't access....  
    }  
    ....other stuff I can access here...  
}  

public class worker
    {  
    public PageObject p = new PageObject();  
    }  

public class workerchild extends worker  
{  
    p.Buttons.    <---don't have access to Buttons public variables, only .class, etc.  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p.Button` is a classname.
Like any other classname, it can only be used to access static members.

You need to get an *instance* of the `Button` class. (eg, `p.new Button().foo`)

Comment: hm I still get an error trying this example. 'Cannot resolve symbol Button'.    String s = (new p.Button().foo);

Comment: Sorry; that should be `p.new Button()`.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your inner class is called Button (singular), not Buttons (plural). Second, make the inner class static and the `foo` member a constant and you will be able to access the `foo` member as simply `Button.foo`, you just won't be able to change its value.